# Overflow scroll in css disables the Window.ScrollY property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ecmascript-6

When I apply an

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to my div, the global property

```
window.scrollY;
```

stays at 0 instead of getting the window's y property.

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking `document.body.scrollTop`, it returns the current page-scroll value of the page. It being 0, implies you are on the top of the page while executing that instruction. (Try to execute this instruction in console after scrolling the page a little)

You can get the desired value by fetching that div DOM element and finding it's scrollTop value. (element.scrollTop)

Comment: Yeah i've already scrolled past the top of the page. I've also tried using document.defaultView.scrollY and window.scroll . when scrolling past 0 or the top I still get 0. Although when i disable overflow: scroll; it works fine. would you like me to reproduce it ?

Comment: Use the scrollTop value

Comment: window.scrollTop gives me undefined

Comment: Try it yourself. Giving an overflow: scroll sets the window.scrollY property to 0.

Comment: now check the correct version. 

as i told the scrollTop property beloongs to the DOM element.You can fetch the element in and if has overflow scroll, you can egt the scrollTop value of that element. 

window object doesnt have the scrollTop value, I check thoroughly . 
if you want the scroll value of page, you can use `document.body.scrollTop`

Comment: Ok so I got it working, basically the browser doesn't calculate the scrollY without the proper styling conditions. So I just altered some positioning and heights. I probably should have asked the question better looking back at it.